# Check how many queries are sent to DB while viewing a Blade in Laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a collection.

```php
$items = Item:where('count' , '>' , 5)->get();
```

And I have an array of ids.

```php
$ids = [2 , 4 , 7 , 8];
```

In my Laravel blade, I want to show each on $items based on ids array. I did something like this:

```php
@foreach($ids as $id)
    <a href="#">
        {{ $items->where('id' ,$id)->first()->name }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

It's working perfectly. The question is, how many queries am I sending to the database? Is the following running a new query?

```php
$items->where('id' ,$id)->first()->name
```

Because I already `get()` the items from the database. Another question is, how can I find out how many queries are being sent to the database while displaying the view/blade?

Comment: you can try [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: use Telescope, queries tab, and you will see every query performed on page load. incredibly useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check/debug all queries executing on a page in laravel: (below code can be inserted in roots file)

```
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
    var_dump($query->sql);
    var_dump($query->bindings);
    var_dump($query->time);
});
```

Comment: thank you. i used this code and got the time of DB query. i have two questions: 1- is the $query->time miliseconds? and another question is i have 500,000 records in my database and loading the query time with pagination takes 100 miliseconds. is that ok ?

Comment: Hi
1. Yes the query time is in miliseconds.
2. That totally depends on that data being fetched. 100 milliseconds sounds okay to me!
Please accept the solution if it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

It gets only one query, and then the method where() is apply after get, is only a filter from original items in that case.

Also, you can install a logger db to check what querys is doing , for instance, Laravel Debugbar

Answer (score 2):

You can always check network tab and select XHR that will show every request.
Also u can use

```
{{ $items->find($id)->name }}
```

much smoother :P

hope it helps :D

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for DB queries inside you method:

```php
$counter = 0;
\DB::listen(function($sql) use (&$counter) {
    $counter++; //increment for each query was run
});
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#listening-for-query-events)

Answer (score 1):

You have already gotten your items from the DB, so no queries are being run. You are using the where() function of a Laravel Collection, which is a function that filters based on the key, value pair you provide. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where

Answer (score 0):

you can use the popular Debug

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Its very simple and illustrative!